# How to get list of members in particular group using LINQ in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, linq, umbraco, roles, membership

I am doing the following for Member search in Umbraco

var members = from p in Member.GetAllAsList()
                        select p;

and now I need to filter the members using one or more member groups (roles)..

Answer (score 3):

From [this post in the umbraco forums](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/3048-How-to-retrieve-a-members-membergroups#comment10186) by a member of the umbraco core team:

> If you are using Umbraco 4 I would strongly recommend that you use the
>   standard ASP.NET methods to get back the roles. For example you should
>   do this:
>
> var roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser("user_name");
>   This will then go via the umbraco.providers.members.MemberRoleProvider
>   by default, or any custom ASP.NET role provider you choose to
>   implement.
>
> Directly interacting with the Member API is no longer recommended.

The Roles class also has a method called [FindUsersInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.findusersinrole.aspx), which you could use as follows:

```
var usersInRole = System.Web.Security.Roles.FindUsersInRole("roleName", "%");
```

The second parameter is for matching the username, but it accepts SQL wildcards, so this should return all users in the role "roleName".